# Remove space between text lines in button tag

Tags: html, css

When my answer choices go to two lines I get a lot of space in between each sentence in my button tag. I 've tried setting the

```
display:block;
float:left;
```

which didn't work. What I want to happen is that when the button gets more then one line, there is reduced space in between the sentences. Here is my code and my snippet.

P.S I know I have a lot of inline CSS. This is due to the application I am using called Ionic Creator which puts them their.

[Image snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrALE.png)

HTML

```
<div class="answer-div">
        <button style="font-weight:700;color:#32575E;font-size:28px;margin-left:15%;" id="a_one" value="" class="button button-royal button-large button-outline answer-choices"></button>
        <button style="font-weight:700;color:#32575E;font-size:28px;margin-left:4%;" id="a_two" value="" class="button button-royal button-large button-outline answer-choices"></button>
        <div class="spacer" style="width: 602.391px; height: 26px;"></div>
        <button style="font-weight:700;color:#32575E;font-size:28px;margin-left:15%;" id="a_three" value="" class="button button-royal button-large button-outline answer-choices"></button>
        <button style="font-weight:700;color:#32575E;font-size:28px;margin-left:4%;" id="a_four" value="" class="button button-royal button-large button-outline answer-choices"></button>
        <div class="spacer" style="width: 602.391px; height: 41px;"></div>
        <button style="font-weight:500;font-size:28px;" id="submit" value="" class="button button-royal button-large button-block submit">SUBMIT</button>
        <button style="font-weight:500;font-size:28px;" id="correct" class="button button-royal button-large button-block submit">CORRECT!</button>
        <button style="font-weight:500;font-size:28px;" id="submit-fake" class="button button-royal button-large button-block submit active"></button>
        <button style="font-weight:600;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:36px;" id="maggies_drawers" class="button button-assertive button-large button-block maggies_drawers">MAGGIE'S DRAWERS</button>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
.answer-choices {
    width: 35%;
    height:29%;
    border: solid 1.5pt #32575e;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a small `line-height`setting, like `line-height: 1` or even less (0.9 in my example snippet):

```css
.answer-choices {
  border: solid 1.5pt #32575e;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 0.9;
  width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<button style="font-weight:600;color:#333;font-size:36px;" class="answer-choices">MAGGIE'S DRAWERS</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the line-height property of the element in question to something smaller?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head sounds like you need to set the line-height property in the CSS. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Example: line-height: 1.4;